# How to debug and fix this double free memory corruption issue for specific case

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a QT based GUI when I exit the tool, I get this following issue

```
*** glibc detected *** /bin/linux_x86_64/main-g: double free or corruption 
(!prev): 0x00000000049eca50 ***
  ======= Backtrace: =========
   /lib64/libc.so.6[0x3feee75e66]
   /lib64/libc.so.6[0x3feee789b3]
    /linux_x86_64/main2- 
   g(_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIPN3zi_14PCommandEE10deallocateEPS3_m+0x20) 
  [0x1d9f504]
 gui//../bin/linux_x86_64/main2-g 

  _ZNSt16allocator_traitsISaIPN3zi_14PCommandEEE10deallocateERS3_PS2_m+0x2b) 
  [0x1d9f0de]
 /gui//../bin/linux_x86_64/main2-g   
(_ZNSt12_Vector_baseIPN3zi_14PCommandESaIS2_EE13_M_deallocateEPS2_m+0x32) 
[0x1d9eba6]
/gui//../bin/linux_x86_64/main2- 
 g(_ZNSt12_Vector_baseIPN3zi_14PCommandESaIS2_EED2Ev+0x41)[0x1d9e955]
../bin/linux_x86_64/main2-g(_ZNSt6vectorIPN3zi_14PCommandESaIS2_EED1Ev+0x41) 
 [0x1dc771b]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__cxa_finalize+0x9d)[0x3feee35ebd]
 ../lib/linux_x86_64/lib-g.so(+0x3a627c6)[0x7f63
 ====== Memory map: ========
 00400000-02b5f000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 21767481                           
   ../main2-g
 02d5e000-02f8c000 rw-p 0275e000 08:03 21767481                           
../main2-g
  02f8c000-03222000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
03cc7000-04cac000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
```

I need some inputs to debug this issue. I am also not able to use Valgrind . It crashes before this case

Comment: More information is usually helpful for an answer.

Comment: If I get such errors they let me doubt whether C++ was really a good choice. The wrong code might have been executed much earlier. Memory corruption happens at a time (e.g. by out-of-bound access) but doesn't need to cause an immediate crash. Instead, something unrelated is overridden e.g. a pointer. Now, this starts an avalanche and finally it's hard to guess where it started. I'm afraid Valgrind would really be your best option to uncover this (as it can recognize the original out-of-bound access). Otherwise, you may use "ancient" techniques: divide and conquer.

Comment: ...i.e. separate parts of application and test them isolated. (Btw. since I use smart pointers, it became much better - not so much doubts about C++ anymore...) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

One of your delete or free calls are done on already freed memory. Go through all your manual memory deallocations and check if they are correct (remove suspicious ones and see if it changes the behaviour).

Ideally using modern C++ you should have small or no need for explicit new and delete (use std provided smart pointers).

Regarding Qt, beware that Qt uses a parent child ownership. You should only delete "top" objects (ones that has no "parent" set), Qt will delete all children of a deleted object on its own. i.e. if you have manually allocated a QObject derived instance and in some way chained it into an QObject hierarchy (add child/set parent/ etc), deleting that object directly will cause trouble.